# When I run composer on Windows, I get an error of 'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Tags: php, windows, composer-php, git-bash

I have an install of Acquia Dev Desktop 2 for local Drupal development, which comes with PHP and some tools like composer and drush.  However, when I run composer, it gives me the error:

```
'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have already seen many other similar questions on here, which universally say that php needs to be added to the PATH.  However, I have already done this adding:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\php7_3_x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools //contains Composer and Drush
```

This results in me being able to run php and php.exe from Git Bash fine, but if I try composer the aforementioned error still crops up.  It's not working on Powershell, cmd or git bash for windows, but I am in particular trying to get it to work on Git Bash so here is my .bashrc.  I've tried lots of other variations, but to no avail.

```
alias php='php.exe'
alias php.exe=\'C:/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\DevDesktop\\php7_3_x64\\php.exe\'
alias drush='drush.bat'
alias composer='composer.bat'
```

I'm at a loss on what steps to take, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Put the PHP folder in your path, git-bash will find it then and so will any attempt from a windows cammand window

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hi thanks for your response, but I've already done this

Comment: Don't forget to restart the computer after setting environment variables

Comment: Sigh...yup a restart did it.  I thought closing and opening Git Bash was sufficient.  Thanks @KenLee

Answer (score 0):

D'oh, needed to restart my computer.  Many thanks to Ken Lee!